# How to remove cabinet drawer from rails

Tags: cabinets, drawers

I need to remove a soft-close drawer from its rails so I can access the back of the shelf body. Nobody, including the contractors who originally spec'd and installed it, knows the hardware manufacturer or how to remove it.

Ideas?

**Side, showing hardware**
[image]

**Side view**
[image: Side view]

**Bottom looking up**
[image: Bottom looking up]

**Alternate view of bottom of shelf looking up**
[image: Bottom of Shelf looking up]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out... you pull / lift, using lots of force.

Comment: Peter there are usually 2 ways lift and pull or small tabs you push down to release the slides. Please up vote your answer so it will be closed or we keep seeing it come up forever. BTW good job on figuring it out, DIY projects get eaisier with more experiance and we will be here to help on the tougher ones that you need more help with.